# Launch screen file using Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

In my Swift based iOS project I have multiple targets (brands) and for each target I have created custom .xib file for Launch Screen File. I wonder if there is any way of setting .xib files (Launch Screen File) using Swift?

Now I have to manually click in project setting under Targets -> General -> AppIcons and Launch Images. Unfortunately this is general setting and it sets chosen .xib for all brands.

Comment: You can select the option in File inspector to set the .xib to be used as a Launch Screen

Comment: I have found a solution. In plist file under Launch screen interface file base name add $(TARGET_NAME) and set to string. Next step is that you have for each of your targets .xib file with same name as your target name is. For example if you have target named Test_03 just rename .xib file in Test_03.xib